# Jquery: Keyup event is not fired, on dynamically added input controls

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following

```
$('input[type = text]').on('keyup', function (e) {

});
```

works great on static created control

```
<input id="txtSearch" type="text" class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-lg-12">
```

but does not fire, on controls created dynamically and rendered as

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="idName" name="textBox">
```

via a mixture of ajax json response and html.

```
jQuery.each(response.controls, function (index, item) {
    var input = jQuery("<div class='form-group'><input type='text' class='form-control' id='" + item.id + "' name='textBox'></div>");
    jQuery('#fields').append(input);
});
```

What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For dynamically created element use [*delegated event*](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/):

```
$('body').on('keyup', 'input[type=text]' function (e) {
```

Answer (score 2):

Since your `<div class='form-group'><input type='text' class='form-control' id='" + item.id + "' name='textBox'></div>` is a dynamic element.

You need to bind the key up event after you have appended it. For example.

```
jQuery.each(response.controls, function (index, item) {
    var input = jQuery("<div class='form-group'><input type='text' class='form-control' id='" + item.id + "' name='textBox'></div>");
    jQuery('#fields').append(input);
    inputevent();
});

function inputevent() {
    $('input[type = text]').off('keyup').on('keyup', function (e) {

    });
}
```

Or you can bind your keyup event as delegate by referencing to your wrapper element i.e. `#fields` in your case. So, the code might look as follows:

```
$('#fields').on('keyup', 'input[type=text]', function (e) {

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
jQuery(document).on('keyup','input[type = text]',function(){
    //execute your code, when dynamically added content is keyupped
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
catchKeyup(id) {
    // code here...
}
jQuery.each(response.controls, function (index, item) {
    var input = jQuery("<div class='form-group'><input type='text' class='form-control' id='" + item.id + "' onkeyup='catchKeyup(" + item.id +")' name='textBox'></div>");
    jQuery('#fields').append(input);
});
```

If you are creating input by any response of request. Maybe you should use general function for keyup. In this way you could use input keyup function.

Answer (score 0):

For the element added dynamically to DOM, you need to bind the event to them using `on()`

```
$(document).on("keyup",'input[type=text]', function(){
//do your work
});
```